# Using a mixin nested inside another selector/class

Tags: css, less, less-mixins

I'm trying to make a Mixin output two different things based on context. Like so:

```
.seticon(@r,@g,@b) {
    b {
        background-color: rgb(@r,@g,@b);
    }
    &.act b {
        .box-shadow(0 0 5px 1px rgba(@r,@g,@b,0.45));
    }
    &.act.hover b {
        background: #000;
        .box-shadow(inset 0 0 0 3px rgb(@r,@g,@b) !important;
    }
}

.nonreceivable {
    .seticon(@r,@g,@b) {
        b {
            background: #000 !important;
            .box-shadow(inset 0 0 0 2px rgb(@r,@g,@b));
        }
    }
}
```

Now `.seticon` works as expected, but `.nonreceivable .seticon` doesn't seem to work. Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong or isn't this intended by the Less developers? How would you instead solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Is `nonreceivable` class applied to the same element or parent element? if it's parent, it should work. Otherwise, put an `&` in front of `.section`

```
.nonreceivable {
 &.seticon(@r,@g,@b) {
    b {
        background: #000 !important;
        .box-shadow(inset 0 0 0 2px rgb(@r,@g,@b));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Adding a `&` in front of the mixin name wouldn't really work mate. It would actually cause a compile error (atleast in the latest versions of the compiler).